# StratifiedKFold failing to produce 9 distinct folds - Python 3.7

Tags: python, scikit-learn, split

I am struggling to properly utilize `sklearn`'s [`StratifiedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) code.

I have an extremely large dataset (`X`), and subsequent list of classes (`y`), that is imbalanced. I am looking to break that up into 9 stratified folds.

However, The results are not what I am expecting. I am essentially appending the entire dataset each time, and creating 9 folds of the entire dataset. What is quirky, is that I am not looking to get a train and test split for each fold, I just want a stratified split of my data. (i.e., take my data / 9 by maintain the class imbalance).

```
# https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 9, random_state=8, shuffle=False)

# Lists to hold the fold data and the fold classes
fold_data = []
fold_classes = []

print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)

unique, counts = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)
print(dict(zip(unique, counts)))

# Split into 9 splits
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):    
    # Get the first fold
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape) # Why this shape so big? 
    
    # Use numpy to concatenate the training and testing data
    temp_data = np.concatenate((X_train, X_test), axis=0)
    temp_classes = np.concatenate((y_train, y_test), axis=0)
    
    # Append the current fold to the overall folds
    fold_data.append(temp_data)
    fold_classes.append(temp_classes)

print("overall size: {}".format(X.shape))
for x in fold_data:
    print("Example fold size: {}".format(x.shape))
```

Yields:

```
(240970, 3291)
(240970,)
{0: 196365, 1: 44605}
(214195, 3291) (26775, 3291)
(214195, 3291) (26775, 3291)
(214195, 3291) (26775, 3291)
(214195, 3291) (26775, 3291)
(214195, 3291) (26775, 3291)
(214195, 3291) (26775, 3291)
(214195, 3291) (26775, 3291)
(214195, 3291) (26775, 3291)
(214195, 3291) (26775, 3291)
```

I have looked at various resources, and cannot figure out how to properly accomplish what I am doing. I am looking for something that effectively creates something to the effect of 9 distinct folds, no overlapping data, with dimensions of approximately `26,774` rows, with each class maintaining its split (about `21,818` of class `0` and `4956` of class `1`)

**UPDATE**
I tried using `StratifiedShuffleSplit` but get the same problem. Each fold is all of the data, not 1/9 of the data.

Comment: From the [docs on StratifiedKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) - "Generate test sets such that all contain the same distribution of classes, or as close as possible.". This means to get the class split you want, you'll likely need to do it manually. I don't know of any library/package provided functions that allow control of the class distribution in the fold generation.

Comment: This makes sense. This won't return 9 folds of size `(26,774, 3291)` but return the full dataset split into train and test where the test set is 1/9 of the data.

Comment: To get around this you could store the test indices of each fold and then use this to build your 9 splits of data.

Comment: @Harpal wouldn't there be a (likely) chance that, in some of the folds, there is an overlap (i.e., some index will appear more than once?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the 9 splits by storing the test indices at each split and then use these to create your 9 data splits

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
import numpy as np

X = np.zeros(240970 * 10).reshape(240970, -1) # shape: (240970, 10)
y = np.random.randint(5, size=240970) # shape: (240970, )

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=9, shuffle=False)

splits = []
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y): 
    splits.append(test_index)

# Flatten the test indices
flat_idxs = np.concatenate(splits).ravel()

# Check the number of unique indices equals the shape of X
np.unique(flat_idxs).shape[0] == X.shape[0] # True
```

This doesn't create overlapping test indices with the other splits because each test set should be unique.

Comment: and then fold creation would be somethings like: `for idx in splits: data_folds.append(X[idx]) class_folds.append(y[idx])`?

Comment: Yup, that should be it.